# Qt3D change notification system usage example of QSceneChange

Tags: qt, qt3d

I need to listen for changes in the Qt3D scene tree (node added, removed, property changed, etc...).

I found class [`QSceneChange`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3dcore-qscenechange.html) but documentation is missing and I can't find a usage example.

How to use this class to watch for node create/destroy events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is a bit old (and maybe you have already found an answer) but I'll try to shed some light on this issue:

You can listen for changes on the nodes you created. I.e. when you add a `QNode` you can connect its signals to your implemented slots. The following signals are available:

- *Node removed*: [`nodeDestroyed()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3dcore-qnode.html#nodeDestroyed)
- *Parent changed* (i.e. the node was set to a different parent): [`parentChanged()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3dcore-qnode.html#parent-prop)

These two signals are emitted by `QNode`, and thus, all the inheriting classes. There is no *Node added* signal because you know when you created nodes and add them to the framegraph. All framegraph classes inherit from `QNode` so they emit those signals (`QEntity`, `QAttribute`, ...).

---

*All other signals depend on the respective inheriting class and are thus emitted by them.*

For example, if you want to listen to changes in the properties of a `QAttribute` you have to connect slots to the signals of that class. You can see such a list [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qattribute.html#signals).

---

Some more explanation:

The `QSceneChange` is not meant for you but for the back-end. Qt3D uses a front-end - back-end scheme where you use front-end nodes like `QEntity` or `QAttribute` or whatever - i.e. [all classes inheriting](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3dcore-qnode.html) `QNode` are front-end nodes (see the "Inherited By:" section in the link).

When you visit their GitHub repo and look for example at the [`render folder`](https://github.com/qt/qt3d/tree/dev/src/render), you see that there's a `backend` and a `frontend` folder.

The `frontend` folder holds all the `Q`-classes, like `QEntity` and so on. The `backend` folder holds the corresponding back-end nodes, `Entity` in this case. I'm not sure why they didn't separate everything properly but if you check out the [`framegraph folder`](https://github.com/qt/qt3d/tree/dev/src/render/framegraph) you'll see the same pattern again - some classes starting with a `Q` and the corresponding classes without the `Q`.

[image]

Now, the front-end notifies the back-end about changes in its nodes using `QSceneChange` so that the back-end can act accordingly. The creators of Qt3D probably thought it not necessary to have a signal that notifies you about all changes. most of the time you would want to subscribe to one specific property changed event, like `byteStrideChanged()` in `QAttribute` (Why would you want to react to each and every change?).

I assume you could somehow intercept those `QSceneChange` events (new implementation of `QNode` or something like that) but they are not meant for you.